How to Disable/Delete the Pesky Dictionary Popups on Mac OS using Visual Studio Code?
Apple's Dictionary app and Visual Studio Code don't work well together.  I get constant popups from Dictionary, an app that I have not, and will not ever use.
I've followed the instructions in Apple's Support Forum:

Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
Click Services in the left column
In the Searching section, click the arrow to expand the options
Remove the checkmark from "Look Up in Dictionary"

This stopped most of the popups, but on occasion, Dictionary shows up to haunt me while using VSC.
I tried nuking it from terminal:
sudo rm -rf /System/Applications/Dictionary.app

Which results in a screen full of error errors:
rm: Dictionary.app: Operation not permitted

I currently running a Macbook Pro 2017, with Ventura 13.6.7.
I recall in the older versions of the OS, you had to boot into the recovery drive to remove system files, or enable system-wide full disk access, but I don't know the best solution using Ventura.
What is the best approach to this problem?  Nuke the app, or find another way?
How can I delete/disable the Dictionary app, permanently?

Dictionary.app is inside the SSV, you're not deleting it without much more effort than it's worth.  Is this helpful?  https://support.apple.com/en-us/102309

You can’t delete that app and the real problem is VSCode is using Apple API that enable data detectors. Let’s see if we can find a way to turn off data detectors either in that app or on macOS.

The Dictionary app itself is unlikely to be the cause of system-wide popups that access the same data. In any case, you can't modify the core OS anymore.
If you've disabled the shortcuts, could it be that the dictionary is being triggered by 'Force Click'?
These options in the Trackpad panel of System Settings may be relevant.


Thanks, that's probably the issue.  I'll accept your answer in a week or so if I don't get any dictionary popups :D

This fixed the problem,  thank you.  As a 12 year Mac enthusiast, it saddens me to see where Apple has gone:  data collectivization, planned obsolescence, and even now we have to resort to 3rd party apps like notunes to fix their, buggy, uninstallable applications.
